# SAML - How to use Service Provider login page?

Tags: spring-saml

I had a requirement to implement spring security saml implementation. 
And I want to connect to IDP(Identity Provider) to authenticate without using IDp's login page. In my case, I want to use Service Provider (login page)..

Is this possible? If yes how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with WSO2IS with request path authenticators which validates user credentials comes from SP login request. If you take SAML2 SSO scenario, SP can send SAML2 Auth request using POST binding to IDP. In the same request SP can send the end user's credentials that is retrieved from the login page of SP application. Then you would not see the login page in IDP and credential are retrieved from auth request and validates with IDP's user store. If success SAML2 response is generated. You can take help from this [link](http://soasecurity.org/2015/02/12/sso-without-identity-provider-login-page/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a good idea since by definition, the service provider is not supposed to authenticate users, that is the IDP's responsibility. 
If you are concerned about branding.. you may be able to request the IDP to personalise their login page if your SP has requested authentication although it is slightly unlikely that they will agree to this.